# Как предотвратить снятие всех чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть несколько чекбоксов, они отмечены.

Надо предотвратить снятие всех чекбоксов - должен быть выделен хотя бы один. Т.е. последний выделенный не должен сниматься.

Как такое сделать в angularjs ну или просто джаваскриптом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементарно - в `onchange` у отдельного чекбокса проверяйте,сколько у вас всего отмеченных чекбоксов, если `0` - для `e.target` ставьте `checked` обратно.

Comment: Вообщем дал им класс checkbox_filter и написал onchange="if($('.checkbox_filter:checked').length<1){this.checked = true;}" .  Ещё пример, кому надо- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgKVm